# includepdf breaks urls when split over multiple lines

Tags: pdfpages, urls

Given the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-]{url.pdf}
\end{document}
```

and the pdf `url.pdf`:

[image]

and the resulting pdf after `pdflatex mwe.tex`:

[image]

The URL in `url.pdf` is clickable (every part of the URL) and leads to URL
https://tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest

The URL in `mwe.pdf` is only clickable on the first line (e.g. the part that says `https://tex.`) and leads to https://tex.

So it seems that the URL is partly preserved since it is clickable, but it breaks when split over more than one line. Is there a way to fix this with pdfpages directly, i.e. without resorting to other tools or middleware?

The environment I have to work with does not allow me to use other tools at this time, so I have only pdflatex and available packages to work with.

Another option (although not preferred) would be to disable URLs in included PDFs completely.

Comment: if you include a pdf with \includepdf annotations (and so links) are lost. If there is still something clickable it is your pdf viewer guessing (and obviously guessing wrong).

Comment: Aha, I was wondering about that. I did read some (old) posts stating that annotations would break, but since it did "somewhat" work I figured that it must be working these days. However, I do see the same behavior in all viewers I tested with: acrobat, chrome, edge